# Eclipse dynamic web project imported from Git: The import XXX cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, git

I created a dynamic web project and a Tomcat 8.5 server in my office computer.
After the day I Git push it to GitHub.
I went back home and try to import the project from GitHub.

[image: After import from git, clone URI]

I've tried Project -> Build Automatically & Clean.
And Right Click on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries to delete and add the JRE(JDK) Libraries again.
Nothing works. What should I do?

Comment: Expand the Java Resources / Libraries node. Is there an unbound classpath container? If not, those standard API classes should be coming from a server--have you targetted one in the project's properties?

Comment: No unbound things, and I did "new" a server and configured the project with it. :/